# NO Data Is Loaded IN Charts Using Sencha Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs

What I need:

- when charts are loaded data is loaded in charts.

Problem I'm facing: Charts are loading but data is not loading.

I'm using sencha docs as Reference Guide.

1. I just want load data in charts link: http://postimg.org/image/ydbac2soh/
2. This is  the output link that I'm getting url: http://postimg.org/image/5whlpe6wj/

This is code of  line charts:

```
Ext.require('Ext.chart.*');
Ext.require(['Ext.layout.container.Fit', 'Ext.window.MessageBox']);

Ext.define('Employee',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:['name','yearOfExperience']
});

var store=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    model:'Employee',
    data:[
        { name:'sam', yearOfExperience:12 },
        { name:'ram', yearOfExperience:7 },
        { name:'kim', yearOfExperience:16 },
        { name:'john', yearOfExperience:21 },
        { name:'Mary', yearOfExperience:13 }
    ]
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.Msg.alert("hello","all set");

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart',
{
    width:500,
    height:300,
    animate:true,
    shadow:store,
    store:store,
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    legend: {
        position:'right'
    },
    insertPadding:25,
    theme:'Base:gradients',
    axes:[
        {
            title:'years Of Experience',
            type:'Numeric',
            position:'left',
            fields:['yearOfExperience'],
            minimum:0,
            maximum:30
        },
        {
            title: 'Employee', 
            type: 'Category',
            position:'bottom',
            fields:['name']
        } 
    ],

    series:[
    {
        type:"line",
        xFields: "name",
        yField :"yearOfExerince"
    }
    ]

    });

});
```

- I have used  dummy data t load in charts in ext js.
- Charts are loaded perfectly but data is not loaded in charts please help  where i have done wrong.
- I have tried with dummy data in charts but no data is loading.
- Here is the output link: http://postimg.org/image/5whlpe6wj/.

Comment: i have formatted my code now please soolve my problem.

Comment: please tell where done wrong thank sr for realizing my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the store to:

```
autoLoad = true;
```

Comment: i have used  autoLoad: true in store but no data is loaded in charts